# Aligning a div vertically

Tags: html, css

I want to align a left div vertically in middle of right div. I am able to do that by using `display:table-cell;` but then I cannot use the `float:left`

Here's what I'm trying:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"><h1><a href="#"><img src ="img.png" /></a></h1></div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;    
    width: 400px;
}

.left{
    border: 1px solid red;   
    max-width: 200px; 
    max-height: 50px;
    float: left;   
    overflow: hidden;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

img{
    display: block;
}

.right{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid green;    
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/fmpLt/

Comment: why would you use float left?

Comment: See what happens if I remove float left.

Comment: you want the "egg" in the right div? why not do so in markup??^^ http://jsfiddle.net/kLHa4/ please make your target soemwhat more clear, I don't get what you want

Comment: No? It's in the left div as you see. I just want it to be vertically in the middle of the right div (ie. the left div moves down about 80px in the example)

Comment: left div vertically in middle of right div??? What does it mean?? you need egg image to be inside the right div?

Comment: @Sowmya thought that too but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I am not clear about what you are expecting, I have tried the below code. check if it can help you

Add `display:table` to .wrapper then `table-cell` to `.left`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpLt/3/)**

---

Another solution with `position:absolute`

```
.wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;    
    width: 400px;
   position:relative; background:yellow
}

.left{
    border: 1px solid red;   
    max-width: 200px; 
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;   
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; margin-top:-25px
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpLt/5/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for and sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: @user1251698 np. u r wlcme

Answer (score 1):

If you know the left div height (eg.50px), you could set a position:relative to the wrapper container and the left div, then set a top position of 50% to the left div, with a margin-top equal to minus 50% of height.

Eg.

```
.wrapper{
    ...
    position:relative;
}

.left{
    ...
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `margin-top` set to half the height of `.right` less half the height of the image.  In this case, that would be `margin-top: 68px`.